# How to make smaller radio buttons

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I can't find a way to create a group of three small (19px high) labelled radio buttons in material-ui. I'm migrating a browser app from static HTML/JS into material-ui/react, and I need the group to stay the same size.

The button group I'm starting with has three small vertically aligned labelled radio buttons. Here's
a screenshot:

[image]

Here's the code for the best I've been able to do using the material-ui documentation:

```
<FormControl
  margin="dense"
  size="small"
>
  <RadioGroup
    size="small" 
    name="dataSource"
    value={dataSource}
    onChange={handleDataSourceChange}
  >
    <FormControlLabel
      value="CaseCount"
      control={
        <Radio
          className={classes.radio}
          size="small" 
        />
      } 
      label="Cases"
    />
    <FormControlLabel
      value="DeathCount"
      control={
        <Radio
          className={classes.radio}
          size="small" 
        />
      } 
      label="Deaths"
    />
    <FormControlLabel
      value="HotSpots"
      control={
        <Radio
          size="small" 
        />
      } 
      label="HotSpot warning"
    />
  </RadioGroup>
</FormControl>
```

This results in an oversized group -- the button icons are too large, the text is too large, and each row is 38 pixels high (twice the 19 pixels of the original). Here's a screenshot of the material-ui counterpart:

[image]

I think I want the result to use a vanilla html input (with type of `radio`) instead of an svg icon, and a font with font-height of `13px`. How do I do that in material-ui?

I know how to fix the padding-left so I'm not worried about that. How do I get rows that are 19px high instead of 38px?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Reason

If you inspect the Material radio button, we can see that the padding of the radio button is causing each row to have a height of 38px.

[image: Radio button padding]

## Code

Therefore, we can simply remove the vertical padding from all radio buttons with the following code (note that my code is slightly different than yours):

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  // Applied to <Radio />
  root: {
    width: 19,
    height: 19,
    paddingTop: 0,
    paddingBottom: 0,
  },
  // Applied to <FormControlLabel />
  label: {
    fontSize: 13
  }
});

export default function RadioButtonsGroup() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("CaseCount");
  const classes = useStyles();

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
  };

  const customRadio = <Radio size="small" classes={{root: classes.root}} />;

  return (
    <FormControl component="fieldset">
      <RadioGroup value={value} onChange={handleChange}>
        <FormControlLabel classes={{label: classes.label}} control={customRadio} value="CaseCount" label="Cases" />
        <FormControlLabel classes={{label: classes.label}} control={customRadio} value="DeathCount" label="Deaths" />
        <FormControlLabel
          classes={{label: classes.label}}
          control={customRadio}
          value="HotSpots"
          label="Hotspot Warning"
        />
      </RadioGroup>
    </FormControl>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit on CodeSandbox]

[image: Results]

## Explanation

According to the [`Radio` API documentation](https://material-ui.com/api/radio/#props), we can apply custom styling to root of the radio button by [overriding styles with classes](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#overriding-styles-with-classes) using the class name of `root`. Therefore, we first define a style object called `root` in the `makeStyles()` function. Next, we apply the styling to the `Radio` component by adding the prop of `classes={{root: classes.root}}`:

```
<Radio size="small" classes={{root: classes.root}} />
```

Similarly, according to the [`FormControlLabel` API documentation](https://material-ui.com/api/form-control-label/#css), we can apply custom styling to the text label using the `label` class name. Therefore, we first define a style object of `label` in the `makeStyles()` function. Next, we apply the styling to the `FormControlLabel` component by adding the prop of `classes={{label: classes.label}}`:

```
<FormControlLabel classes={{label: classes.label}} /* ... */ />
```